# How to get a line number under cursor

Tags: android, cursor-position

Given a multi-line EditText, how can I know the line number at cursor position?

Comment: This SO question may give you some further insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528004/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-contenteditable-area-and-current-caret-line-positio

Answer (score 0):

Something like 
textview.getPaint().measureText(textview.getText().toString()) / textView.getWidth();

This assumes the cursor is at the end of the text, if not you gotta use substring measure.

Sorry for brevity on my iPad

Answer (score 0):

There exists a workaround for your problem.

This SO question may give you some further insights: [How to get number of rows in ContentEditable area and current caret line position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528004/how-to-get-number-of-rows-in-contenteditable-area-and-current-caret-line-positio)

Answer (score -1):

Take the text of the control and put it in a string.  Loop over the string up to the index of the cursor position and count the number of newlines.

Comment: The text is wrapped. I has no newlines.