# How to get number of rows in ContentEditable area and current caret line position?

Tags: html, wysiwyg, contenteditable, caret

my question has two parts, but they are related.

Firstly - I have Contenteditable DIV with some text and I need to get total number of rows (lines) of this DIV. Is it possible ?

Secondly - I need to get caret row position, if it is on row number 1, 2, 3, etc....

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The direct answer is that there is no method that actually gets you those numbers. However, there are a number of different work arounds which you can apply to **estimate** (I use *estimate*, because I don't think they can be made 100% accurate) those values.

To answer your first question, how to get the number of lines in the element. Assuming the element uses a consistent `line-height`, you can find the number of lines by dividing the element `height` with the `line-height`. This of course gets significantly more complicated if you got elements with `margin`s, `padding`s, or differentiating `line-height`s within the  element. If that isn't enough of a problem, the `line-height` property doesn't necessarily have to be a numerical value, i.e. it can be `normal` or a % etc. There's quite a few questions regarding the `line-height` property and how to get a numerical representation of it here on SO so I won't go too much into detail on that. For the sake of rest of my answer, I did specifically assign a common `line-height` across the element.

The far more problematic part of your question is finding the caret position within the element. Again, there isn't a method which will just return you the right answer. Instead, one approach you can take to **estimate** the caret row position is to make a `range` at the current caret position (`selection`), insert a dummy node there, get the nodes `offset` relative to the containers `offset`, calculate the number of lines based on the `top offset` of it, and then remove the dummy element.

Additional problems with the dummy element arise when you can't `hide()` it or leave it empty.

It seems like a very bad way of doing it, and it is. It certainly doesn't work flawlessly when trying to navigate with arrows. So why not just use `getClientRects()` for the `selection`? It works fine when it is just text without any space or such, but immidiately when you throw a few `<br /><br />` in there, it won't return you the line position there anymore. Additionally, when you are at the first or last character of a line, it would give sometimes incorrect line rows, as it throws the element either up or down depending on the amount of space available.

If you are looking for a fool-proof way of finding the caret position and number of lines, there **isn't one**. If rough estimates are enough, than my solution is a good start (it certainly could use some more work, and support for IE which should be lot easier in this case as the `TextRange` object actually gives offsets in pixels).

My take on this:

```
var lineHeight = parseInt($('#editable').css('line-height'));
//var ce = $('#editable')[0].getClientRects();
var ce = $('#editable').position();
console.log("Lines: "+$('#editable').height()/lineHeight);
$('#editable').bind('click keyup keydown',function(){
   if(window.getSelection){
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
      range.insertNode($('<canvas />').attr('id','tempCaretFinder')[0]);
       var p = $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').position();
       $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').remove();
       console.log("Caret line: "+(Math.ceil((p.top-ce.top)/lineHeight)+1));

    }else if(document.selection) { 
        // the IE way, which should be relatively easier. as TextRange objects return offsets directly.
        range = document.selection.createRange();  
    }

});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/mKQUH/

**EDIT: Try 2**
http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/mKQUH/129/

As mentioned, creating dummy elements made the caret jump all over the place sometimes, so I had a go again with the getClientRects() for ranges. To make them more feasible, I made the selection extend itself one character, then create the range, then check the Rect position, and then move the caret back one character.

Why?

Because the caret on the first character of a line, would have its top parameter at the same level as the previous line, so with applying an extra character to it, it can check whether it is actually a new line. Another problem with the getClientRects() was that it didn't work on empty line breaks. To accomodate this, I used the previous creating of a dummy element as a fallback in those situations.

End result:

```
var lineHeight = parseInt($('#editable').css('line-height'));
//var ce = $('#editable')[0].getClientRects();
var ce = $('#editable').offset();
console.log("Lines: "+$('#editable').height()/lineHeight);
$('#editable').bind('click keyup keydown',function(e){
    //alert($(window).scrollTop());
   if(window.getSelection){
       var save = window.getSelection();
       var s = window.getSelection();
       s.modify('extend','forward','character');
     // s.modify('extend','forward','line');
       range = s.getRangeAt(0);
       var p = range.getClientRects();
       var top;
       //console.log(p);
       if (typeof p[1] != "undefined"){
           top = p[1].top+$(window).scrollTop();
               }else if (typeof p[0] != "undefined"){
                top = p[0].top+$(window).scrollTop();    
               }
       else{
          // sigh... let's make a real work around then
           range.insertNode($('<canvas />').attr('id','tempCaretFinder')[0]);
       var p = $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').offset();
       $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').remove();
           top = p.top;

       }

     // console.log(top-ce.top);
       console.log("Caret line: "+(Math.ceil((top-ce.top)/lineHeight)));
       save.modify('move','backward','character');
       /*
       range = s.getRangeAt(0);
      range.insertNode($('<canvas />').attr('id','tempCaretFinder')[0]);
       var p = $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').position();
       $('canvas#tempCaretFinder').remove();
       console.log("Caret line: "+(Math.ceil((p.top-ce.top)/lineHeight)+1));
       console.log(e.which);

       switch(e.which){
           case 40:
             s.modify("move", "forward","line");

             break;  
                    case 38:
             s.modify("move", "backward","lineboundary");

             break;  
       }
       */


    }else if(document.selection) {
        // the IE way, which should be relatively easier. as TextRange objects return offsets directly.
        range = document.selection.createRange();  
    }

});
```

Comment: @Niklas Thanks for answer, I can live with "pretty-good-estimate" as you have written here. However, there is one small bug in your example and I really can't find what's wrong. When you click somewhere in the middle of some line, it seems that contenteditable element remembers this horizontal location and when you use arrows to move up and down, the caret changes horizontal position on each line, which is kind of frustrating. Normal behaviour when using up and down arrow keys would be, that the caret just jumps up or below current line, but doesn't changes its horizontal position.

Comment: @Frodik I noticed that too (on firefox only though), and I do believe it is a result from creating an element and injecting it in there, and then removing it. I tried changing the solution into using getClientRects(), but it had even more problems than this solution. I know exactly the problem you are on about, but I unfortunately did not find a solution for that.

Comment: @Niklas I am using Chrome and it behaves the same. Could you please think through your solution once again if it is possible to overcome this problem. Because otherwise this solution would be useless, normal users couldn't live with it for sure.

Comment: @Frodik Alright, here we go. Try 2: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/mKQUH/129/ updating my answer with what I did differently

Comment: @Niklas Thanks for the update ! Although, I see few new minor bugs. Sorry if I'm beeing picky, but if you could rid of those as well, it would make your solution fully usable. 
The problem #1 is when you hit the "End" key on any of the lines, the caret doesn't jump to the end of the line, it rather goes to the beginning of the next line.
The problem #2 is that wherever the caret is placed horizontally, when you use arrows UP or DOWN, it always jumps at the beginning of the line and doesn't keep the horizontal position.
The problem #3 - it is not possible to navigate to the last letter...

Comment: @Niklas - The problem #2 is cause by line-height beeing set smaller than the original line-height, in your case 18px. If it is set to bigger value, this problem doesn't appear

Comment: @Frodik well the End key event can be captured and manually probably placed accordingly and #3 you could probably check whether it is at the end of the content and do some fix for that. I'll try and have another look at this this week if I get some spare time.